# cómo sumar mas de tres elementos en listas bidimensionales

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, numpy, array-bidimensional

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Estoy tratando de sumar cada elemento que tengo en una lista1, luego tengo que sumar cada elemento que tengo en una lista 2, y después en una tercera lista (que no tengo) debo incluir el residuo de dividir cada elemento de mi lista1 entre la sumatoria de mi lista 2.

```
suma1 = 0
suma2 = 0
coseno = []

for k in range(i,j):
   coseno.append[()]+= i/suma2
   for j in lista2:
      suma2+=j
      for i in lista1:
          suma1+=i
```

Me dice "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" u otros errores, ya he intentando con varias cosas pero nada parece funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido te estás liando un montón. Primero anidas un montón ciclos que en principio no necesitas porque no tienes que recorrer una lista al completo por cada item de la otra.

Por otro lado:

coseno.append[()]+= i/suma2

- `coseno.append[]` es simplemente sintaxis inválida. `[]` se usa para indizar y `append` es un método de `list`, debe ser llamado no indizado. Es decir, `()` y no `[]`.
- Corregido lo anterior `coseno.append(())` agrega una tupla a la lista.
- Para terminar `coseno.append(()) += i/suma2` resulta en otro error de sintaxis porque intentas asignar a la llamada del método...

Si quieres agregar el resultado de la división, sería simplemente:

```
coseno.append(i / suma2)
```

No obstante, eso calcularía la división no el resto. En princiopio deberías hacer algo como:

```
lista1 = [1, 3, 7, 8, 9]
lista2 = [4, 8, 9]

suma_lista1 = 0
suma_lista2 = 0
lista3 = []

# Sumatoria lista2
for num in lista2:
    suma_lista2 += num

# Sumatoria lista1 y residuos
for num in lista1:
    suma_lista1 += num
    lista3.append(num % suma_lista2)
```

O usando `sum` y una lista por compresión:

```
lista1 = [1, 3, 7, 8, 9]
lista2 = [4, 8, 9]

suma_lista1 = sum(lista1)
suma_lista2 = sum(lista2)
lista3 = [n % suma_lista2 for n in lista1]
```

O usando NumPy:

```
import numpy as np


array1 = np.array([1, 3, 7, 8, 9])
array2 = np.array([4, 8, 9])

suma_array1 = array1.sum() 
suma_array2 = array2.sum()
array3 = np.mod(array1, suma_array2)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Intenté pero la respuesta no me da según lo esperado. Tengo entendido que los for deben estar anidados y por eso los hice así. La fórmula que tengo que replicar es la siguiente: [Google](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18-mz703defidkGshOju0Dgm9DSHXC4If/view?usp=sharing) Este es un enlace insertado a lo que se pide. Si me pudieses ayudarte lo agradecería.